# How to display all the questions for a quiz app using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am unable to display all the questions, whenever i am trying start quiz it is only showing 1st question & showing error.It is showing a type error cannot read property of 'questions' undefined. Whenever i click on start quiz it is displaying 1st question & showing the error

--Select--
      {{i}}.{{title.title}}

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="selectQuiz">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSubmit()">Start Quiz</button>

        <div *ngIf="showButton">
          <div class="card-content white-text">
          <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
            <span class="card-title">{{currentQuestion+1}}</span>
            <p>{{quiz['questions'][currentQuestion]['text']}}</p>
```

quizcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuizService } from '../services/quiz.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quiz',
  templateUrl: './quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz.component.css']
})

export class QuizComponent implements OnInit {
form: FormGroup;
QuizTitles = [];
Quizquestions;
selectQuiz;
quiz;
QID = [];
  answer: any;
 userData: any;
 currentQuestion = 0;
 showButton = false;
 Value;

constructor(
private router: Router,
private quizService: QuizService,
private formBuilder: FormBuilder

) {

}
getTitles() {
this.quizService.getQuiztitles().subscribe(data => {
const aData = Object.values(data);
aData.forEach((title: string, id: number) => {
 this.QuizTitles.push({
  title,
id
               });
      });

});
}
onSubmit() {
this.showButton = true;
this.quizService.getQuizQuestions(this.Value).subscribe(data => {
this.quiz = data;
console.log(this.quiz.questions[this.currentQuestion].text);
});
}


startQuiz(value) {
this.Value = value;
}
ngOnInit() {
this.getTitles();
}





OnSubmit() {
console.log(this.answer);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please put all the pertinent code and clarify your question? For example `QuizTitles` is in your template but not in your class. Also you haven't wrote the error you get. Take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

rather than using

```
<span class="card-title">{{currentQuestion+1}}</span>
 <p>{{quiz['questions'][currentQuestion]['text']}}</p>
```

you should use *ngFor* to show all questions, I think the issue is in

```
{{quiz['questions'][currentQuestion]['text']}}
```

you are trying to show questions without increasing counter

*UPDATE*

you are using subscribe, the html file will load before subscribe is finished so use loading to wait for Observable to get all data then view the questions

Comment: sorry i didn't get it Can you please explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

Your `quiz` property does not exist when you loads your component because your are updating it inside a subscription.

{{quiz['questions'][currentQuestion]['text']}}

Comment: I added it but it is showing Template parse error. Parser error.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, no need to run foreach in subscribe, you should add boolean variable like ready = false, and in template file in ready = false ( it shouldn't run the template before ending subscribe and get data.
pls see the code

```
 getTitles() {
    this.IsLoading = true;
    this.quizService.getQuiztitles().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.QuizTitles= res;
        this.is_ready = true;
      },
      error => { }

    );
  }


    this.quizService.getQuizQuestions().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.quiz = data;
        this.is_ready_quiz = true;
      },
      error => { }

    );
  }
```

in html file

```
 <div *ngIf="is_ready_quiz" *ngFor="let item of quiz" >
     <p>{{item['questions'][currentQuestion]['text']}}</p>
    </div>
```